# Using ionice Over Cluster

Tags: nfs, cluster, io, gridengine, ionice

**Background:**

I use a computing cluster at work (4 slave nodes and 1 head node) that uses the SGE job scheduler.  Recently we've been running jobs that do some heavy IO and it has been slowing down shell/vim usage (small IO, but we need it running smoothly 24/7).  I found ionice, and it seems like a perfect solution for one computer, but I'm not sure it will be helpful on a cluster...

**Question:**

If I run a process (let's say vim) through the head node with a ionice setting (-c2 -n0), will it still have any priority over processes on other computers (high IO on slaves -c2 -n4) to the shared HD?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What provides "the shared hd" and how is it accessed?

Comment: This may be related to http://serverfault.com/questions/265871

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ionice` command will only affect contention for IO among processes that are operating on the same machine. It won't help with a device that has contention from many machines unless the machine `ionice` on is running a process serving those machines.

You probably want to partition your operating system(s) onto a different spindle(s) from all of your working cluster data.